# Why and when would "num" be used?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

According to what I understand *num* is used when the asker of the question is already aware that the answer will be no. Does this have any other uses besides rhetorical questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Num* can also be used in questions that *expect* the answer "no", even if they're not rhetorical.

> *Num pater eius es?*
>   Surely you're not his father?
>   You're not his father, are you?

You could certainly reply "yes, actually, I am" to this question (*immo* in Latin); it's just not the answer the questioner expects.

Answer (score 7):

For **direct questions**, *num* is one of the the explicit ways, together with *nonne* and *-ne*, of signalling a yes/no question. Whereas *-ne* is neutral and simply asks for either confirmation or denial of some detail (that is, the respondent can reply either 'Yes' or 'No'), *nonne* and *num* are used to ask leading questions.

When *nonne* is used, the person who's asking the question expects to receive the answer 'Yes' or 'Yes, of course'; and, as you've noted, when *num* is used, the answer 'No' or 'No, of course not' is expected. Questions with *nonne* are sometimes translated by saying something like 'You *did* see Cicero, didn't you?' (*nonne Ciceronem vidisti?*), questions with *num* by saying something like 'Surely, you didn't see Cicero, did you?' (*num Ciceronem vidisti?*).

For **indirect questions**, *num* loses its negative leading force. Both it and *-ne* just mean 'whether' ('if') (*nonne* retains its positive leading force though).

> *rogavi num Ciceronem vidisset* = *rogavi Ciceronemne vidisset.*
>   I asked whether he had seen Cicero.

Although Allen & Greenough, *New Latin grammar* says (§332, b, Note) that *num* in indirect question '*commonly* loses its peculiar force' (emphasis added), I don't remember ever seeing instances where such a *num* had to be construed with negative leading force.